# Definition of Differentials through Surreal Numbers

Tags: calculus, analysis, surreal-numbers

It is fairly well known that nowadays derivatives are defined primarily by use of a limit argument. I think I recall that when the idea of derivatives was first introduced (and limits had not yet been used) there was some criticism because the method of computing derivatives/justifying them required the notion of an absolutely small positive number (epsilon).

I am wondering whether the concept of surreal numbers would allow for exactly this definition of derivatives/differentials to be mathematically valid as well. After all, surreal numbers would allow for an epsilon that fits the description above. It would also justify why higher-order terms can be neglected in a derivative (because higher order terms represent differentials raised to even higher powers, which must then belong to even smaller groups of surreal numbers.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: I am not an expert in this, but I read that the surreal numbers contain the hyperreal numbers and these are constructed to do nonstandard analysis, and this was introduced to formalize the intuition of Euler of others. That implies among other things that derivatives can be defined without the limit concept, as You can read about e.g.[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number)

Comment: So the answer is: look for the topic "nonstandard analysis" for this approach.  Surreal numbers have a lot of other structure in addition to what is needed for doing derivatives through infinitesimals.